# Using a 12V switch in 120V circuit

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, insulation

Can I use a 12VDC switch rated at 16A on a 120VAC circuit that only use 0.5A-1A? I have a similar switch, that is 120V rated at 10A, but it's a little too small.

Comment: Current and voltage are not to be traded against each other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

The insulation in the 12V switch is not designed to withstand 120V (really 170V).

Comment: I have tested the 12v switch on a 115 psu, and see no problem.

Comment: @Atmega328 then why did you ask the question?

Comment: I don't have other switch, and I need to use that switch. I asked to make sure it's safe.

Comment: @Atmega328, its not safe, it will probably work for a while but is likely to eventually do one of the following: fuse open, fuse closed, spark, start a fire.

Comment: Do you have an AC rating for the switch? AC and DC ratings can be hugely different, so your switch may be ok, but still risky unless you check.

Comment: Switch ratings come from their ability to open a circuit with a certain voltage across them, while conducting the rated current. A 12V switch is not guaranteed to open under 120V. When the switch opens a small arc forms, driven by the voltage and current present when the switch opens. Over many cycles arcing will erode the contacts and increase their resistance. This can cause excessive heating over time. Worst case your switch could weld closed, or catch fire. Depending on construction quality you might wind up with hazardous voltages present on the switch lever. Just don't do it.

Comment: @user83582 If you did not see a problem during your test, you did not test very carefully. You need to test also with humid and dusty air and deposits of dirt on the switch. But if the insulation distance is smaller than required by the rules, no further test can prove the switch is good for 120 V AC. Did you measure the open switch insulation resistance using a high voltage and very low current to detect Gigaohm?

Answer (score 1):

Running too high a voltage on a switch would mean the the switch is not properly insulated for the  voltage which could cause the power to arc either bypassing the switch or shocking the user.

Answer (score -1):

No. You can't use that switch.
The switch would heat up a lot and sometimes can cause an electric shock if you touch it.
This is because the insulation would be provided for the specified voltage and current.

Comment: Heat has almost nothing to do with it, no I take that back, it has nothing to do with it.